# Which is better approach to stop sql injection

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, sql-injection

I have database function which select data on different where condition's.There is two possible approach to achieve this.
First

```
    public string select(string name)
    {
        string s = null;
        query = "select * from tablename where name=@name";
        con.Open();
        com=new SqlCeCommand(query,con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
        sdr=com.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            s = sdr.GetString(0);
        }
        return s;
    }
```

In this approach i need to code different function for small change in query like order by , address in place of name or more than one parameter in where query , top 20 etc. But this approach is secured in terms of sql injection.
Second

```
    public string select(string query)
    {
        string s = null;
        con.Open();
        com=new SqlCeCommand(query,con); 
        sdr=com.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            s = sdr.GetString(0);
        }
        return s;
    }
```

In second approach I pass database query in function argument with values so i don't need `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);` and don't need to code different function for changes in selection query. Parameter's value in query is given by code not by user.Is sql injection possible in this approach as user is not giving input for parameter.

Which one is safe side and efficient because my application can't bear dataloss.

Comment: I'd bind and validate long before I ever passed data to the persistence layer.  I'd reject it before I ever got to this point.

Comment: Imho the first approach is better
€: duffymo is right, check your input.

Answer (score 3):

Primary Defenses:

Option #1: Use of Prepared Statements (Parameterized Queries)

Option #2: Use of Stored Procedures

Option #3: Escaping all User Supplied Input

Additional Defenses:

Also Enforce: Least Privilege

Also Perform: White List Input Validation

Source www.owasp.org

Comment: which one is better approach according to you from above two .

Comment: in your case the query which is created by system is more secure, if you are performing the client side validation then passing paramerters in side the query will be ok ..but again as i said using store procedure is the better way

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Linq to SQL or EDM?  Using the objects means that your code is (in theory) safe from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: It is amazing to me how much fear/confusion there is of LINQ and Entity Framework (and other ORMs) in some segments of the .NET community.

Comment: Not sure I understand where you are coming from.  My understanding is that the queries are converted to parameterised queries "under the hood", but you can take advantage of the ease of LINQ.  Thats why we use it anyway :)

Comment: I think it's a good suggestion because using it helps eliminate the temptation of implementing shortcuts that don't use parametrized queries. I've seen a lot of legacy .NET code that mixes parametrized stored proc calls with "SQL builder" code that directly builds a SQL statement from user input. If someone forgets to check that user input somewhere else in the program, problems ensue.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for clarifying.  One of my first tasks in this job was to make a case for using LINQ to SQL instead of SPs and SQL Injection prevention was one of the cornerstones of my argument.

Answer (score 1):

> Is sql injection possible in this approach as user is not giving input
>   for parameter.

As long as your user is not interacting with the database, then who will try to inject SQL in your parameters.

Generally as long as you are using Parameters with your query you are safe from SQL Injection.

Comment: is it possible to modify exe to some extent and access second approach for sql injection. I know its type of foolish question but i can't bear data loss.

Comment: If somebody has access to your EXE and can do such thing, then forget about SQL injection, you should be worried about other things. But having said that, your first approach is better than the other.